# Does AES Encryption Decryption Algorithm in Android uses NoPadding?

Tags: android

I am facing this problem with my code.

```
public  byte[] encryptString(String unencryptedData, String encryptionKey) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding", "SunJCE");
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES"); //256-AES, 512-AES
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key,new IvParameterSpec(encryptionKey.getBytes("UTF-8")));

    return cipher.doFinal(unencryptedData.getBytes("UTF-8"));
}
```

Comment: If the data to be encrypted is *always* a multiple of the block size (16-bytes for AES) then padding is not required.

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: However I have encrypted the data but i cannot convert byte[] to hexstring, anyone please provide me the appropriate code.. I need android code :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code to see which providers and algorithm combinations are available:

```
for (Provider p : Security.getProviders()) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Service Name: " + p.getName()));

    for (Provider.Service s : p.getServices()) {
        Log.e(TAG, "     Algorithm:      " +  s.getAlgorithm()));
    }
}
```